# Pilcrow appears in all the column values after importing from CSV file - MYsql

Tags: mysql, csv, import

my CSV content looks like this

```
1234,123;123;123
5675,123;567;234;565
```

No Space is provided at the end of each row in CSV i.e. 1234,123;123;123(No space here)

Imported this using the following command

```
mysql> load data local infile 'E:\sample.csv' into table Test.Table1 fields 
terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' (Column1,Colunm2);
```

It gets executed successfully and i can find all the records in the DB. But the second column ends with a pilcrow.

When i try to edit, the value looks like

```
123;123;123
<extra line here>
```

If i remove the extra line, the pilcrow disappears.

Type of the column1, column2 is varchar.

Any clues for the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is because of EOL termination. The file probably is using `\r\n` instead of only `\n`, hence the "`<extra line here>`".

Comment: I am not sure why there is \r here. Any reasons? I even tried importing the CSV created by exporting the columnvalues from MYSQL. Even that has the same problem. Any insights?

Comment: This is a conundrum. Because every major OS has it's "right" way, however, today, most people are favoring the CR+LF as EOL. Take a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline